# Properly Set Process WorkingDirectory

Tags: c#, process

When setting a process, it seems like I'm not using that variable, `WorkingDirectory`, in the proper manner. I get the error (with a catch)

> ApplicationName='Test.exe', CommandLine='/d=1',
> CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\mb\Desktop\Integration\Tests\dailyTest\dailyTest\bin\Debug\Stress',
> Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

However, in the folder `Stress`, there is a `Test.exe`... , so I really don't understand the meaning of this.

Why is there a failure and how can it be resolved?

---

The code is the following (note that I replaced variable with the direct string contents for better understanding).

```
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "Stress");
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/d=1";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.Start ();
proc.WaitForExit();

return proc.ExitCode;
```

I know the WorkingDirectory is affected by UseShellExecute, however I respected this.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to create the process.

Comment: see the original post!!

Comment: try instead of using workingdirectory to just use the entire path for the filename

Comment: I would use the entire path for the filename, and also include the working directory.  And for both of those I would use Path.Combine to build up the paths.

Comment: Don't do `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "Stress"`, it's why [Path.combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) exists.

Comment: @NissaArmelon Are you sure the generated path exists?

Comment: ok I now use pathcombine, and I'm testing the rest

Comment: it all says they exist, but I always get the error saying it cannot find the files

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Directory.Exists( proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory )` after you set it.  Does `Test.exe` exist in that directory?

Also try:

```
string filename = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Stress", "test.exe" );

check File.Exists( filename );
```

perhaps use `filename` as `proc.StartInfo.FileName`

For your working directory use: `Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  "Stress" )`

To clarify I would say to use:

```
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  "Stress");
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  "Stress", "Test.exe" );
bool folderExists = Directory.Exists( proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory );
bool fileExists = File.Exists( proc.StartInfo.FileName );
```

You can debug to see if the file and folder exist.

Comment: ok here is the result after all the tries. They all exist when I do as you say. However it still doesn't work (even if File.Exists return true), when I execute the code it says
CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
why does it says CurrentDirectory="" when I set the WorkingDirectory? aren't they the same?

Comment: I do this

            string b = Path.Combine (proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory, proc.StartInfo.FileName);

            if (File.Exists( b )) 
            {
                b = "";
            }
                
            proc.Start ();

it says path exist because it goes in the if.
then when I start the process it says this :

Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error :

I was on Linux, so I need to specify that my exe file is executed by "mono"

```
process.FileName = "mono"
process.Argument = "nameOfExe param1 param2..."
```