# run a program using c# return error?

Tags: c#

I am broad-casting using c# OBS open broadcaster I am passing parameters  of my live stream like API's key, url know problem is that here is my code

```
      ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("//mysoftware//obs.exe" , "rtms://334.5.55.55/live  34534-4354-5646-45645");

      Process.Start(info);
```

when i locally pass the path to win explorer windows. It returns the same error as returned by program but a unique scenario when i write the same path in run.exe and along with parameters and then click ok it runs the software.

What the problem the error is

> failed to find locale /en-us.ini file

but program works correctly when i double click on its .exe

but remember i have copy pasted my software in debug folder that is working correctly there.

Comment: I think you need to set the WorkingDirectory of the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483513/how-to-properly-set-process-workingdirectory-in-c-sharp

Comment: If @rene is right, maybe simply try `ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("//mysoftware//obs.exe", "rtms://334.5.55.55/live  34534-4354-5646-45645") { WorkingDirectory = "//mysoftware", };`, using an object initializer.

Comment: proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  "Stress");
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  "Stress", "Test.exe" );

Answer (score 3):

To open OBS from the bash you will need first move to the path in which is obs.exe and then execute obs:

```
cd path/to/obs/

obs.exe
```

To achieve this by using C# you can do the following:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "path/to/obs/"; // like cd path command
startInfo.FileName = "obs64.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```